# CSS file not linking to HTML

Tags: css, html

I've recently started learning to code HTML and CSS by hand for the first time since the mid 90s (last time I tried to build a site, Netscape Communicator Gold 3.0 was out--so bear with me here).

I cannot get my CSS to link up with my HTML. I am using HTML5 conventions and following the code examples in the popular book "Learning Web Design," 4th edition, by Jennifer Robbins. Many of the code examples I see use conventions that are no longer required in HTML 5.0, so my code may be a bit sparse.

I have tried to directly embed the styles in the HTML and they work. However, they do not work when in a CSS sheet. I have tried to load the page in both IE11 and the newest version of Chrome and the page displays in white with default browser settings. My HTML file and my CSS file are in the same directory: c:/RogersReviews. There is an images folder in the directory, c:/RogersReviews/Images. I have linked to an image file in that folder and my code works.

However, I cannot change the background color of my page using a linked CSS style sheet. I have tried to make it red to prove that the link is working. Below is my CSS code followed by my HTML code.

I have used Eric Meyer's browser reset code in the CSS to clear out any browser settings that might be messing things up. I have omitted it for your convenience.

It is probably something minor that I have missed. Thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT: The page seems to be linking just fine when I post it here, but not when I run it from my hard drive by opening the HTML file. I would like to be able to see the page as it would look online, but from my hard drive.

```css
body {
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset=utf-8>
 <title>Rogers Reviews: Academic Book Reviews </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
 <img src="Images/Rogers-Reviews-logo-3.gif" alt="Rogers%20Reviews">
 <ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Authors</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Subjects</a></li>
 </ul>
</header>
<h1> Welcome </h1>
 <p> This site is a collection of academic book reviews, mostly in the humanities and the social sciences. </p>
 <p> The purpose of this site is to assist high school, undergraduate, and graduate history students with choosing appropriate secondary sources for their research papers. An emphasis is placed on older works written before 1960.</p>
 <p> <a href="RRindex.html"> Back to home </a> </p>
<footer>
 <p> &#169; 2014 </p>
 <p> <a href=""> About </a> </p>
 <p> <a href=""> Contact </a> </p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do other styles from the stylesheet load?

Comment: can you open sourcecode in chrome and click on the link from your css? if yes what do you get? with other words if your html file is called `test.html` the URL in your browser should be `path/test.html` and your css should be `path/stylesheet.html`

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine. Have you made sure the stylesheet.css in the same directory as the html file? If you look in the developer tools of your browser and see if the console logs anything that would help as well.

Comment: if it is in a different directory you need to specify the full path to it.

Comment: If you are loading the html file in your browser without the help of a web server (IIS or apache or similar) sometimes IE requires you to use the full path of the `.css` file (with a warning at load time) - the path, hence, could be C:\RogersReviews\stylesheet.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inserted your code, verbatim, into a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vkqyx9w7/), and the background is red, as you wanted.

The code is not the issue, then. Instead, its a problem of the stylesheet loading properly. Try some or all of the following:

- Check your stylesheet name, and that it is the same in the directory as it is in your HTML code; make sure `stylesheet.css` exists properly.
- Double-check that the file exists in the right place, which is in the same directory as your index that you are opening.
- Make sure the stylesheet is loading. In Chrome, if you right-click -> inspect element and go to the sources tab, you can see all loaded resources, including your CSS. If it's not loading here, it could be that it tries to load from your cache. You can force Chrome to load sites without the cache by opening the inspector again, clicking on the gear menu, and checking "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)', and reloading your site.
- Check your local apache/webhost server to make sure that it doesn't have any settings blocking the loading of certain files or types of files. This is assuming you are running one and not just opening the file in Chrome/IE. If that is the case, you should have no problems with the file loading.
- Make sure you saved the file. It's silly, but I can personally vouch for the time when I couldn't make my site update, and I forgot to save/update the file I was viewing.

Comment: Thank you so much.

I disabled the cache and the CSS is still not loading. The inspector in Chrome says that the CSS is not found. However, it does show that the file is part of the directory structure. They are both in the same directory. The CSS file loads in Notepad but not in Chrome's browser. It says file not found. IE opens the CSS.

Comment: Interestingly, IE's element inspector does not show an error. IE also opens the CSS file.

Comment: Could you show me like a screenshot of your file directory, Chrome's inspector (with the file selected), and IE's inspector or something?

Comment: Of course. This is my first time using the site. I've taken four screenshots. Is there a way I can upload them to the thread?

Comment: Via imgur link or something? Not directly, if that is what you are asking.

Comment: Okay.

Here is the link:

http://imgur.com/EqSwkDG,9NFHpcy,In59ech,oVAjGhK#3

The first image shows the directory. The second shows the Google Chrome error on the bottom right hand side. The third shows the lack of errors in IE11 at the bottom. The fourth shows the directory structure in Chrome.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! Figured it out. Note that on the Chrome screenshot, it says "File not Found", yet in your directory, it says "stylesheet.css". Yet Windows Explorer lists it as type of "txt file". If a file has an extension that is "recognized" by Windows, it hides that part of the file name, so the file's name is actually "stylesheet.css.txt". Open your css file in a text editor, click file > save as (or press [ctrl]+[shift]+[s]), and in the drop down for file type, click (*) All Files, and type in, for the name, "stylesheet.css"

Comment: Ah! Bless you sir! That is the culprit.

I noticed the .css in the name and the .txt mismatch in the file type. I thought simply renaming the file was adequate. Simply renaming seems to work fine for changing txt documents to HTML.

Serious thanks for this. It had annoyed me and I had wracked my brain for some time over it. Much, much obliged Aeolingamenfel.

Interesting that Chrome detected an error while IE did not.

Answer (score 1):

Hello, perhaps it helps to someone:

css files have to be transmitted stating "text/css" as content type (while your html page content is usually "text/html").

It is important to state the right value for transmission, because browsers check it.
I had this problem with Delphi, trying to state "DOCTYPE HTML" in a WebBroker application to use HTML5, and the problem has been solved setting it in the variable reponse.contenttype.  If you use a web server, I suppose you have to put the file in the right folder for example, or set this attibute in the right place to instruct your server to send the right contenttype.

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

**Simple solution:** no changes to you html code.

**Procedure:**

**1)** Log into Ubuntu as a `root` user
**2)** Go the `/var/www` directory and right click on the `www` folder, then click `Properties`, change the following permission as follow:

```
view content: anyone
change content: anyone
access content: anyone
```

**3)** Restart apache2 server type `service apache2 restart`
**4)** Finally, test the webpage

Hope this helps

Comment: it's not a good practice to give anybody the full permission.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `href="stylesheet.css"`, try `href="/stylesheet.css"`.

I had the same issue and this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into same issue. It was browser cache. Ctrl-F5 helped to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have created your file in NOTEPAD & not used any editor. While saving the css file, the file type has remained as .txt which leads to saving of the file as Text Document type.

Open a new notepad file, copy & paste your CSS code. Save the file in Notepad under "Save As" menu, enter your css file name with.css extension & ***select "Save as type" as "All Files" documents***. After saving, in the explorer the file type should be displayed as **Cascading Style Sheet Documen**t.

Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue where the css file changes are not reflected in the webpage styling.
Here where the concept of hard-reload helped me. Hard reload can be done by

> shift+ctrl+R

This happens when the browser serves a cached CSS file from that of yours.
To invalidate the cache and serve your latest CSS file, you can perform a hard reload on the browser.

[Refer this](https://sebhastian.com/css-not-linking-html/) For more info on such problems.