# linking between HTML and CSS files

Tags: html, css

I have written my html and css code, but both the files are not linking. I am unable to find any error in the codes.
This is my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>basicapp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/basicapp.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
    </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

The file structure is:

```
/desktop/templates/index.html
/desktop/static/css/basicapp.css
```

Comment: The path of your css file is related to the path of your html file. Try with `href="../static/css/basicapp.css"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS file not linking to HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574753/css-file-not-linking-to-html)

Answer (score 2):

The answer has been provided to you, but here is some more information:

- `/` is an absolute path, e.g. `/index.html` will be at the root of your server, or on your PC most likely `C://`
- or `./` the folder in which the current file resides, this is actually what is happening in your case. `static/css/basicapp.css` will take you to `/desktop/templates/static/css/basicapp.css`
- `../` is the parent relative to the current folder (hence the answers supplied).

## Example

Let's say you have the following structure:

`/folderA/folderB/index.html`

`/folderA/folderB/fileA.html`

`/folderA/folderC/fileB.html`

Say you're in the `index.html` :

To get to file A: `./fileA.html` or `fileA.html`

To get to file B: `../folderC/fileB.html`

*I left out the absolute paths since they tend not to be recommended since you might not know the true root of your website.*

## Your code

> ```html
> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/basicapp.css"/>
> ```

By Rashed Rahat

[Read more](https://www.westga.edu/its/assets-its/docs/understanding_directory_structure_windows.pdf)

**Edit:** Applied Heretic Monkey's comment.

Comment: Note that @ with a user name only works in comments, not in posts. "is the child relative to the current folder" I would say it's the same folder as the one in which the current file resides. Neither ` ` nor `./` navigate up to the parent or down to a child in the directory tree.

Answer (score 0):

As [Poney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4925750/poney) says in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67286766/html-and-css-codes-are-no-linked#comment118933937_67286766): The path of your css file is related to the path of your html file. Try with `href="../static/css/basicapp.css"`

Answer (score -1):

As you mentioned:

```
- desktop
  - templates
    - index.html
  - static
    - css
      - basicapp.css
```

As your **CSS** is on another folder so you have to link any following way:

Try **relative** path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/basicapp.css"/>
```

Or,

Try **absolute** path:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/desktop/static/css/basicapp.css"/>
```

Comment: Answers which provide alternate code with no explanation of why the code presented would work better are often downvoted more than those which do provide an explanation. In this case, the downvote may come from the fact that after proceeding two levels deeper in the folder hierarchy (as `../../` does) from the HTML file, one ends up in a folder with a `desktop` folder, not one with a `static` folder, necessarily.